# How to extract contents(image) of a div by using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

`<div class="product_image clearfix"> 
  <img src="https://res.sastasundar.com/incom/images/product/thumb/XPLOR-Dark-Chocolate-Brownie-1542880911-10051353-1.jpg" title="XPLOR Dark Chocolate Brownie 50 gm" class=" center-block">
</div>`

Using python and beautiful soup

I am not able to find this div by

```
links = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'product_image clearfix'})
```

I have to extract the image after that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full set is loaded dynamically. You can make the same request the page does

```
import requests

base = 'https://res.sastasundar.com/incom/images/product/'
r = requests.get('https://www.retailershakti.com/category/loadBrandListData?MfgGroup=&categoryId=1357&size=50&page=1').json()
images = [base + i['idata'][0]['ProductImage'] for i in r]
print(images)
```

Comment: I don't understand. The url can be found in the network tab (F12) when you refresh the page with F5

Comment: Great! found it. Can you tell me about why the [0] in JSON split and how is the for loop coming after the... what is this syntax?

Comment: The 0 is because i['data'] is a list and you want the first item in that list during the list comprehension. The "loop" is actually a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Answer (score 0):

For the current version of BS, this should work:

```
links = soup.find_all('div', class_='product_image clearfix')
```

Comment: Not working, it is showing no error, but no results are printed

Comment: What happens if you just search for one class, e.g.: `links = soup.find_all('div', class_='product_image')`?

Comment: Same. No results. Compiles Fine

Answer (score 0):

What version of BeautifulSoup are you using. You should be able to print the contents of the divs with:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div class="product_image clearfix">
  <img src="https://res.sastasundar.com/incom/images/product/thumb/XPLOR-Dark-Chocolate-Brownie-1542880911-10051353-1.jpg" title="XPLOR Dark Chocolate Brownie 50 gm" class=" center-block">
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='product_image clearfix'):
  for img in div.find_all('img', recursive=False):
    print(img)
```

Comment: works! like this. But when parsing from a live webpage. not working.  
`https://www.retailershakti.com/category/brand_listing/chocolates-and-brownies/1357`
try on this

Answer (score 0):

For what I gathered form the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), here is a way it would work:

You can get the desired tags by

```
tags = soup.find_all('div', "product_image clearfix")
```

where the second parameter is by default the class name of the HTML element. Then, you can look at a tags children by putting them into a list with `.contents`, or iterating over them with `.children`. In this example, I'll use children for simplicity and use the first found and matching tag to extract the image source from:

```
import bs4

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup("<div class=\"product_image clearfix\"> <img src=\"https://res.sastasundar.com/incom/images/product/thumb/XPLOR-Dark-Chocolate-Brownie-1542880911-10051353-1.jpg\" title=\"XPLOR Dark Chocolate Brownie 50 gm\" class=\" center-block\"></div>")

tags = soup.find_all('div', "product_image clearfix")

img_src = None

for t in tags[0].children:
    if type(t) == bs4.element.Tag:
        img_src = t['src']

print(img_src)
```

The type check is just important because there can be `bs4.element.NavigableString` objects in `tags[0].chlidren`, if there are newlines or spaces, dependig on your HTML parser.